# Cannot connect to (LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB from NodeJS

Tags: c#, node.js, sql-server

Please see the code below:

```
var config = {
    userName: 'sa', 
    password: 'myPassword', 
    server: 'myRemoteServer',
    options: {
        database: 'SampleDB',
        encrypt: true,
        trustedConnection: true
    }
  }


var connection = new Connection(config);

// Attempt to connect and execute queries if connection goes through
connection.on('connect', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('Connected');
  }
```

It works as expected i.e. I am connected to the database.  However, I want to connect to localdb:

```
server: '(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB',
```

When I attempt to connect to server: (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB, then there is an error:

```
"ConnectionError: Failed to connect to (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB
    at ConnectionError (c:\Node\SqlServerSample\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:12:12)
    at Connection.socketError (c:\Node\SqlServerSample\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1016:30)
    at c:\Node\SqlServerSample\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:861:25
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.callback (c:\Node\SqlServerSample\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:69:18)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (dns.js:72:17)"
```

I have spent two hours researching this.  Some webpages say (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB is supported by node.js and some say it is not.  How can I get this working? Please note that SQL Server is not installed on localhost (only SQL Studio Manager).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203283/discussion-on-question-by-w0051977-cannot-connect-to-localdb-mssqllocaldb-fro).

Answer (score 0):

Please use this connection String.

**Data Source=.\sqlexpress**; AttachDbFileName=e:\...***.mdf; Integrated Security=True;